# Class method that is not in the interface

Tags: c#, methods, interface

I have a simple c# question (so I believe). I'm a beginner with the language and I ran into a problem regarding interfaces and classes that implement them. The problem is

I have the Interface `iA`

```
interface iA
{
  bool method1
  bool method2
  bool method3
}
```

and 3 classes that implement the interface: class `B`, `C` and `D`

```
class B : iA
{
  public bool method1
  public bool method2
  public bool method3
}
```

if class B had another method that is not in the interface, let's say `method4()` and I have the following:

```
iA element = new B();
```

and then I would use :

```
element.method4();
```

I would get an error saying that I don't have a `method4()` that takes a first argument of type `iA`.

The question is: Can I have an object of interface type and instantiated with a class and have that object call a method from the class, a method that is not in the interface ?

A solution I came up with was to use an abstract class between the interface and the derived classes, but IMO that would put the interface out of scope. In my design I would like to use only the interface and the derived classes.

Comment: `if(element is typeof(B)) ((B)element).method4();` this should help

Comment: A fresh new user asking a clear and well formatted question. That is rare, congrats and welcome. :)

Comment: Good question. +1 If you give the real scenario, we can advise on the best design aproach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to cast the interface type to the class type; usually we do it by means of **as**:

```
  B b = element as B; // <- try cast element as B

  if (!Object.RefernceEquals(null, b)) { // <- element is B or can be legaly interpreted as B
    b.method4(); 
  }
```

The advantage of "as" is that there's *only one* cast operation, while "is" and (B) have to do *two* casts.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, that is possible. You just need to cast the Interface type to the class type like this:

```
iA element = new B();
((B)element).method4();
```

As suggested by wudzik, you should check if elemnt is of the correct type:

```
if(element is B)
{
    ((B)element).method4();
}
```

Comment: Side note: you can add `if(element is typeof(B))` to ensure that element is `B`

Comment: You probably don't want to be doing this though?

Comment: @Sam Leach: Why wouldn't you want to do this? It's a common task

Comment: But in another idea, can you do this w/o the casting ?

Comment: @RomanoZumbé It doesn't seem right. Maybe create another interface that inherits from the first one and add method4()?

Comment: `is keyword` doesn't work like that, you need `if(element is B)` to make it work

Comment: @user2629277 - it sounds like your mixing together code that just wants to work via the interface (that should work for `B`, `C`, `D` or any other implementation), and code that "knows" specifically that it's working with a `B`. That's usually a sign of a somewhat confused design.

Comment: @Sam Leach. How would you do this if you are for example iterating over the windows Controls collection and want to execute a method on, lets say every Button? In such cases you have to cast.

Comment: @Sam Leach, if another interface is created, then he still wouldn't be able to access it without casting it, as he is still making an instance of iA.

Comment: I agree with both of you. I think the design needs to be re-thought. Depending on the real context it's hard to advise.

Answer (score 2):

Without casting you could do this.

```
interface iA
{
  bool method1();
  bool method2();
  bool method3();
}

interface IFoo : iA
{
  bool method4();
}

class B : IFoo
{
  public bool method1() {}
  public bool method2() {}
  public bool method3() {}
  public bool method4() {}
}

IFoo element = new B();    
element.method4();
```

NB: Try to use capital `I` prefix for C# interfaces.

Comment: This avoids typechecking and casting, but now you have a different object, IFoo. If the user has an iA object, there would still be a need to check if that object is an IFoo (and cast it), to be able to run method4.

Comment: Yes, but design-wise it is smarter to work against interfaces like this, than against concrete types. It's a solution that scales better as it is now easier to extend which types implement the various interfaces.